# MissingResourceException when using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I've used JDBC without any problems many times before, but for some reason on a new server I have it isn't working. The code compiles and runs fine on my main machine, and all the libraries (including the JDBC) should be compiled into a single JAR that I run.

Basic code:

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    System.err.println("Cannot load driver...");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try
{
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?user=dbuser&password=dbpass");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    System.err.println("Cannot connect to database...");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.stackTraceToString(Util.java:355)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:764)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:222)
    at com.test.Server.<init>(Server.java:78)
    at com.test.Server.main(Server.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load resource bundle due to underlying exception java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale en_GB
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:61)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale en_GB
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1539)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1278)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:733)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:59)
    ... 8 more
```

I've never had this kind of error before, and Google is not being helpful at all. I've checked the database credentials, port number, etc. Would appreciate any help on solving it!

Comment: It looks like a driver or classloading issue. MySQL is looking for a bundle containing its internationalized error messages, and can't find it (although it should be bundled within the same jar as the driver classes). How are you building your single jar and running it?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans. I've modified the build.xml to build in the .jar libraries I'm using.

Comment: I don't know about Netbeans, and that doesn't tell me how the jar is built. Does it contain a file named com/mysql/jdbc/LocalizedErrorMessages.class, or a file com/mysql/jdbc/LocalizedErrorMessages.properties?

Comment: Aha! The LocalizedErrorMessages.properties file was missing from the compiled JAR. I believe the build.xml was set up to only include files ending in .class. I've altered the build process to include everything, and it all works now. Thanks!

Comment: @Rsaesha I also was missing the LocalizedErrorMessages.properties file because my build.xml was only including .class file. I think it would be legitimate for you to answer this question yourself and mark it as correct.

Comment: @Rsaesha could you add your solution as answer and accept it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I used Tomcat.

Here is my solution: add the JAR package `mysql-connector-java:<version>` to the `lib` package in Tomcat's (or your server's) installation path.

Answer (score -3):

Replace..

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?user=dbuser&password=dbpass");
```

with ..bcoz default port is 3306 for mysql.If changed give that

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/minebench", "username", "password");
```

and add "mysql-connector-java-5.1.0-bin.jar".
then try it .